# Error: Unable to resolve module `buffer` React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am getting an error when I build my project on Android

> > error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `buffer` from `E:\SUNNYCLOCK-MOBILE\node_modules\safe-buffer\index.js`: Module
> >     `buffer` does not exist in the Haste module map
>
> This might be related to
>   https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968 To resolve try
>   the following:
>     1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
>     2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
>     3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.  4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf
>   /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`.
>       at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (E:\SUNNYCLOCK-MOBILE\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:161:1460)
>       at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (E:\SUNNYCLOCK-MOBILE\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ResolutionRequest.js:91:16)
>       at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (E:\SUNNYCLOCK-MOBILE\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:272:4579)
>       at dependencies.map.relativePath (E:\SUNNYCLOCK-MOBILE\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:376:19)
>       at Array.map ()
>       at resolveDependencies (E:\SUNNYCLOCK-MOBILE\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:374:16)
>       at E:\SUNNYCLOCK-MOBILE\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:212:33
>       at Generator.next ()
>       at step (E:\SUNNYCLOCK-MOBILE\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:297:313)
>       at E:\SUNNYCLOCK-MOBILE\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:297:473
>   BUNDLE  [android, dev] ./index.js ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓░░░░░░░░ 51.9% (813/1143),
>   failed.

my React native info is

```
Environment:
  OS: Windows 10
  Node: 8.9.1
  Yarn: 1.7.0
  npm: 4.6.1
  Watchman: Not Found
  Xcode: N/A
  Android Studio: Not Found

Packages: (wanted => installed)
  react: 16.3.1 => 16.3.1
  react-native: 0.55.4 => 0.55.4
```

How can I solve this issue

Answer (score 41, accepted):

**First** Install the missing dependency `buffer` :

`npm install buffer --save` OR `yarn add buffer`

**Second**

Up in the top of your file using `buffer`:

```
import { Buffer } from 'buffer';
global.Buffer = Buffer;
```

*If you don't need to access Buffer directly, just paste the above code in your App.js file*

Comment: I am not using buffer in my app

Comment: but it's required as a dependency i guess by another npm module, plz revise my answer

Comment: let me try this

Comment: I think npm install buffer --save helped me

Comment: this one works on me but leads to another error