# react native - debug [object Object] handleException - Observable

Tags: javascript, react-native, debugging, observable, aws-appsync

I am setting up a react native [subscription](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/api) via `{ API, graphqlOperation } from 'aws-amplify'`.
When I try to perform a subscription I get the cryptic message shown below.

```js
ExceptionsManager.js:44 [object Object]
reportException @   ExceptionsManager.js:44
handleException @   ExceptionsManager.js:113
handleError @   setUpErrorHandling.js:23
reportFatalError    @   error-guard.js:49
__guard @   MessageQueue.js:386
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue  @   MessageQueue.js:110
(anonymous) @   debuggerWorker.js:69
```

this is the function that is creating problem:

```js
import { API, graphqlOperation } from 'aws-amplify';

...

    const subscribeControlMsg = () => {
        const test = `subscription subscribeUserControlMsg{
            subscribeUserControlMsg{
              id payload
          } }
        `;
        const subscription = API.graphql(
            graphqlOperation(test)
        ).subscribe({
            next: (data) => console.log(data)
        });
    };
```

in `index.js` I already configured the endpoint via `Amplify.configure(config);`.

The error is thrown by

```
API.graphql(graphqlOperation(test)).subscribe({
     next: (data) => console.log(data)
});
```

which is a

```js
(method) APIClass.graphql({ query: paramQuery, variables, authMode }: GraphQLOptions): Promise<GraphQLResult<object>> | Observable<any>
```

Some of the things that I tried:

- json.stringify APIClass.graphql... Nothing pops up on the console
- testing the appsync endpoint. On the AWS console it works
- checking the network tab of the react native debugger. The error occurs before anything is sent over the network
- subscribe and immediately unsubscribe and console log. I get `{"_observer":{},"_state":"ready"}`. No error is thrown

Currently using `"react-native": "0.61.5","react-redux": "^7.1.3" and "redux": "^4.0.4"`

How do you debug a [object Object] error, related to an Observable?

Comment: try `onsole.log(JSON.stringify(data))`? to see the JSON parsed object

Comment: Like this?


`const subscription = API.graphql(
            graphqlOperation(test)
        ).subscribe({
            next: (data) => console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
        });`


Same error. I think the callback is never executed. The observable is created, then it throws an error before the callback is executed. This is probably why no error is shown if I unsubscribe immediately. 

What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

after a lot of testing I figured out that amplify uses the RxJs library.
Every Observable has 3 callback functions: start, next, error. So to debug it, I just needed to console.log the error and attach it to the callback, like so:

```js
let dataP = API.graphql(graphqlOperation(test)).subscribe({
            error: (error) => console.log(error),
            next: (todoData) => console.log(todoData)
        })
```

Comment: the error was caused by a missing dependency
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55226768/error-unable-to-resolve-module-buffer-react-native